# haxe 3 migration - how do I change this for valid haxe 3?

Tags: haxe, openfl

I'm porting an extension (HypTwitter) for haxe 3...
What do i replace

```
haxe.Int32.and(x,haxe.Int32.ofInt(0xFF))
```

with for valid Haxe 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haxe 3 uses `Int` to represent `Int32` values, so you should be able to solve your problem by doing the following:

```
x & 0xFF
```